# textFieldDidBeginEditing: is not called although delegate is connected

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is my code:

In **.h** file

```
@interface VTViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

**In .m file**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.postText.delegate = self;

}

#pragma mark - textField delegate


- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    NSLog(@"textViewDidBeginEditing:");
}

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    NSLog(@"textViewDidEndEditing:");
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```

The last one works, the first two do not since I do not see the NSLog being printed. I also tried connected the textfield in the IB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing your methods up - some are text **view** methods and some are text **field** methods. Check the names from the appropriate delegate protocols and replace as required.